# JodaTime: cannot resolve symbol "convert"

Tags: java, jodatime

I've imported an old project which uses JodaTime into IntelliJ. Everything works fine *except* for FromString and ToString which depend on:

```
import org.joda.convert.FromString;
import org.joda.convert.ToString;
```

For some reason these imports and only these, cannot be resolved.

What't wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The joda-convert is a separate project: http://www.joda.org/ found under http://www.joda.org/joda-convert/

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the Joda-Convert-project, too, see [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-convert/releases).

Answer (score 0):

### Dependency Information ([source](http://www.joda.org/joda-convert/dependency-info.html))

**Apache Maven**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Apache Buildr**

```
'org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.9.2'
```

**Apache Ivy**

```
<dependency org="org.joda" name="joda-convert" rev="1.9.2">
  <artifact name="joda-convert" type="jar" />
</dependency>
```

**Groovy Grape**

```
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.joda', module='joda-convert', version='1.9.2')
)
```

**Gradle/Grails**

```
compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.9.2'
```

**Scala SBT**

```
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.9.2"
```

**Leiningen**

```
[org.joda/joda-convert "1.9.2"]
```